# PHP7.0 package doesn't exist on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

I used the following command. It can install for php version 5.5 but php7.0.
How to install php 7.0 on utuntu 14.04?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-fpm php7.0-gd php7.0-json
    php7.0-mysql php7.0-readline
```

Comment: follow this link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: do you really want an old version of php, on an old (no longer supported) version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use php7.0 with ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I think Tim's point was that maybe it's time to upgrade instead of running unsupported versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked to make sure that the packages you want are available in that ppa repo? Because PHP 7.0 is, under package name php7.0, but only for ubuntu versions 16.04, 18.04, 18.10, and 19.04.   In fact, it looks like that's what most of his whole repo supports.  He even states he only supports versions of Ubuntu that are still supported. So, you're not going to be able to install your packages from his repo unless you upgrade.

Comment: how to check ppa repo?

Comment: When I install php7.0, display the error message [package php7.0 doesn't found].

Comment: I'll post a link here for you to look at the repo.  As you can see on the page, Ubuntu 14.04 is not supported. Ppa repository is [here.](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+index?batch=75&direction=backwards&memo=225&start=150)

Comment: Thank you. Please help me how to use PPA repository?

Comment: @user3480687 listen to what megaEmailman is telling you. 14.04 is **not supported** by the PPA. That means you **can't use it**. Stop trying to use an ancient version of Ubuntu. Upgrading is free and not too difficult

Comment: @user3480687 you should also consider targeting a supported version of PHP. Only 7.2 and 7.3 are currently supported. 7.0 is not. See https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php. unless you want to run without the benefit of security updates and bug fixes (both for Ubuntu and PHP) then you should always make sure you use a supported version. Plus, as you've discovered, it makes installing things much easier, because 3rd parties tend to withdraw support for related packages once the main product stops bring supported. That is exactly what has happened with this PPA.

Comment: Please explain me next question that can only php5 be installed in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Unless you can find a repository with a newer version of php, that still supports Ubuntu 14.04, that's right. And basically nothing supports Ubuntu 14.04 anymore. I would suggest upgrading to a new LTS release. They're generally good for five years.

Comment: @user3480687 "can only php5 be installed in Ubuntu 14.04" . No.  You can either a) see if you can find another PHP7 package (via a PPA or manual download) which is built for 14.04 specifically, or b) try to install PHP7 (and all its dependencies) yourself direct from the source code and configure it. But this is not a simple task. However the point is: why would you want to?? Upgrading your ubuntu version will likely be quicker and easier. And also you are then at much less risk of security problems because you have support from the vendor.

Comment: Yeah. I mean, running a process that could give someone access to a command line on your device and literally having no type of security or support services just sounds like too much of a risk to take.

Comment: @MegaEmailman in fairness that's a bit of a mis-characterisation of the risk. In reality unfortunately people run unsupported O/Ses all the time due to all sorts of issues requiring legacy (versions of) code to continue in service. They usually take other measures to harden them / reduce access to them in those circumstances. It doesn't leave you with "no security", it just means you don't get any new security patches, so if a new vulnerability is discovered then you are vulnerable to someone trying to exploit it, since you won't receive any fixes for it.

Comment: Sorry, I misworded that. I had meant security services or support services. And by security services, I meant things like patches and vulnerability fixes.

Comment: Thanks for your patient. Please could you help me next question.   How to install nginx 1.4.6 on ubuntu 16.04?